# FileDataStoreFactory and posix on android?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I'm looking into making a simple calendar application on android and was thinking of using google calendar API, and target SDK 24 and up, but I see a potential problem, google doesn't have an equivalent implementation for [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview) on android, but they do have a java implementation, which leads to another problem, a hidden POSIX implementation which I'm not sure how to get around, it's inside their `new FileDataStoreFactory(...)` [method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java). What are my options and is there a way around this? If I run on SDK 26 it works fine, the authorization flow .setDataStoreFactory method, but anything below that I will get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/nio/file/attribute/PosixFilePermission;
at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory.setPermissionsToOwnerOnly(FileDataStoreFactory.java:141)

// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)

* * * this is the part where i will struggle if i have to use an SDK lower than 26 * * *
.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH))) 

.setAccessType("offline")
.build();
```

for more reference, please peek at their github for the [FileDataStoreFactory class](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/blob/master/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/util/store/FileDataStoreFactory.java) , on line 77 is where the issue happens `setPermissionsToOwnerOnly(dataDirectory);`

and after doing a bit more digging I believe I've found a clue why Paths isn't working inside the FDSF, because of the minimum [SDK requirement](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Paths) 'Paths was Added in API level 26'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a work around for this, so I avoided working with DataStoreFactory which uses API 26 Paths, and instead I used a good-old mkdir and changed it's permissions accordingly. Afterwards, I set things up with a Credential store and now my application is working with SDK 24, SDK 25, and SDK 26+ using the google calendar api. I'd also like to mention that it took some heavy work digging into outdated issues regarding this, as well as digging in manually into the actual implementation of DataStoreFactory to understand better.

```
private val TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH: String = "tokens"
private val CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH: String = "credentials.json"

val inputStream: InputStream = activity!!.resources!!.assets!!.open(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)
        val clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, InputStreamReader(inputStream))
        val mDirectory: File? = File(activity.filesDir.absolutePath + File.separator + TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)
        if(!mDirectory!!.exists()){
            mDirectory.mkdir()
            mDirectory.setReadable(true,true)
            mDirectory.setWritable(true,true)
            mDirectory.setExecutable(true,false)
        }
        val mFile = File(mDirectory, CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)
        mFile.setReadable(true, true)
        mDirectory.setWritable(true,true)
        mDirectory.setExecutable(true,false)

        val mFileContents: String =
            activity.resources.assets
                .open(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

        mFile.outputStream().bufferedWriter().use { out ->
            out.write(mFileContents)
        }

        val mCredentialStore: CredentialStore? = FileCredentialStore(mFile, JSON_FACTORY)
        //val fileFactory: FileDataStoreFactory? = FileDataStoreFactory(file)

        this.mFlow = GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
            .Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setCredentialStore(mCredentialStore)
            .setAccessType(ACCESS_TYPE)
            .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

No workarounds required now. Google added support for lower Android versions (API 19+) below Android 8 (API 28) for [google-http-java-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client) in version [1.36.0](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/releases/tag/v1.36.0) with [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/pull/1070) commit in July 2020. Just import this,

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory
```

in the file where you are using **FileDataStoreFactory** and add this dependency in app's **build.gradle** file,

```
// Replace 1.38.1 with latest version number from https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/releases
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.38.1'
```